# Qt and windows messages

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, qt5

I want to receive custom messages in Qt via the [QAbstractNativeEventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractnativeeventfilter.html). Basically I added a `switch WM_USER + 1:` in the implementation, but I get notifications even though I am not sending anything. I assume that Qt could be using user messages internally as well. Is there a way to know the last id QT is using so that I can use the first free?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `WM_USER` range of messages is owned by the code that called `RegisterClass()`.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031202-00/?p=41653) In this case, that would be Qt, which is using that range for its own purposes. You will have to consult the Qt documentation to see what range of messages are available for you to use. This might be the `WM_APP` range, but if Qt uses *that* as well (and doesn't provide a way for you to request a message to use), you'll have to deal with registered window messages and their shortcomings. Again, check the Qt documentation.

**EDIT, since I wasn't clear enough the first time**

Do **NOT** try to find some random `WM_USER + n` that you can use. The point of the link I put there is that Qt is free to use all of the `WM_USER` messages for whatever it wants. Ignore this and your code **will** break in a future version of Qt. You **must** consult Qt **documentation** to see whether Qt specifically defines a set of messages in the `WM_APP` range (or even in the `WM_USER` range, but this must be explicitly stated in the documentation) as safe to use, and if not, you have **no choice** but to call `RegisterWindowMessage()` to register a system-wide named message. Ask on the Qt mailing list if necessary. Checking the source is not going to work because the current source is not a contract for future versions of Qt.

Comment: I hoped Qt headers have a macro or smth, that defines the last WM_USER + n value used, but no, so sadly I just had to stick with a random value that did not figure in my search for WM_USER in Qt sources. Sad:(